# Is useEffect inside custom hook considered a bad practice?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I was trying to create a reusable hook which includes 2 other mutation hook from react query which does 2 different operations. I was successfully able to create my custom hook and everything is working as expected. My only question is, while building the hook I had to use a useEffect inside my custom hook. I am just wondering if it is a bad practice to have a useEffect inside a custom hook and do I need to change my approach? Will there be any performance issue because of this? Is there something I should be aware of?

Comment: It's a very common pattern, not bad practice at all. In fact, whenever you see `useState` and `useEffect` inside a component you should ask yourself if that should be a custom hook. Most of the time the answer will be "yes". Personal opinion on this though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a very common thing to do. [The official documentation describes a custom hook that uses `useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook) ([an example in new documentation](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks)).

The only thing you should be aware of is that, as always, your hook isn't supposed to intentionally break hook isolation by maintaining an arbitrary shared state outside the hook itself.

Comment: *your hook isn't supposed to maintain any shared state* - what do you mean by this?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I refer to intentionally breaking hook isolation by maintaining an arbitrary shared state outside the hook itself

Comment: This is the link to the new documentation: https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks